# Difference between gparted and df hard drive sizes

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, gparted, disk-usage, df

In `df -h` output I can see:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on                                                                                   
/dev/sda1       234G   60M  222G   1% /media/daniel/0dabcbae-b766-4aba-84f0-f7ab39b354fb
```

So where is 12 GB that are not used and not available simultaneously?

I checked it in `gparted` and see:

- size 238.47 GiB
- taken 4.80 GiB
- available 233.67 GiB

```
233.67 + 4.8 = 238.47
```

so in `gparted` result is logical. Selected File system ext4.

I can't remove 4.8 GB from this hard drive. I formatted it to
ext4, fat32, again ext4 and still there is shown visible amount
of used space.

#### Question 1.

Why I can't wipe hard drive?

#### Question 2.

Why results from `df` are different than from gparted?

#### Question 3.

Why sum of used and available is not equal to size in `df`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ext4 reserves a portion of space, typically 5%, to avoid fragmentation and for system services. This is specific to ext4

See [How To Free Reserved Space On EXT4 Partitions](https://odzangba.wordpress.com/2010/02/20/how-to-free-reserved-space-on-ext4-partitions/). But use it at your own risk.

This should explain why the total partition size you see by both apps don't match. gparted reports the total partition size, while dh ignores the reserved space.

Regarding that 1% of usage, all filesystems need some space to track files (aka overhead and metadata), even when there's no files yet. FAT32 has very low overhead but still has some, while complex journal-based filesystems like ext4 and ntfs need more space.

It's not that you can't wipe that used space, it's that after the disk gets wiped, it gets filled again.